# Why is score instance variable not decreasing when it should in python

Tags: python, oop, variables

I've been starting to learn oop and im having difficulty making it do what i need it to. I'm building a simple game using the turtle module where a circle is dropped and everytime the circle drops out of the screen the score should decrease.Ill be adding shooting functions and speed configurations and all that. But at the moment I'm stuck on this circle loop.

The problem is the score is not changing correctly. I have two classes Circle and Player. The score is an instance variable of Player class, but drop() function in Circle class tallies the score.

I can make it work using a procedural style of programming but with oop im stuck.. Heres code. Any constructive criticism is welcome.

```
import turtle as t
import random

class Circle:

    def __init__(self,size):
        self.size = size
        #self.speed = speed
        self.circle = t.Turtle()
        self.ypos = 300



    def size_color(self):
        self.circle.color('red')
        self.circle.shape('circle')
        self.circle.shapesize(self.size,self.size,1)

    #positions circle random x top y
    def posit(self):
        number = random.randint(-340,340)
        self.circle.ht()
        self.circle.penup()

        self.size_color()
        self.circle.goto(number,self.ypos)
        self.circle.st()


    #substracts from y position for falling effect
    #should substract from score as well
    def drop(self):
        self.posit()
        while True:

            self.ypos = self.ypos- 4
            self.circle.sety(self.ypos)
            if self.ypos <= -300:
                Player().score = Player().score - 10
                print(Player().score)
                self.ypos = 300
                self.posit()



class Player:
    def __init__(self,score=200):
        self.score = score

def display_screen():
    window = t.Screen()
    window.bgcolor('black')

display_screen()
c = Circle(2)
c.drop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Every time you call `Player()` you're creating a new player. So when you do

```
Player().score = Player().score - 10
print(Player().score)
```

it's roughly equivalent to:

```
temp_player1 = Player()
temp_player2 = Player()
temp_player1.score = temp_player2.score - 10
temp_player3 = Player()
print(temp_player3.score)
```

As you can see from that, there are 3 different players, so you're never decrementing any player's score, and then you're printing a different player's score.

You need to add a `player` attribute to the `Circle`, then it can use `self.player` instead of creating a new player each time.

```
import turtle as t
import random

class Circle:

    def __init__(self,size):
        self.size = size
        #self.speed = speed
        self.circle = t.Turtle()
        self.ypos = 300
        this.player = Player()

    def size_color(self):
        self.circle.color('red')
        self.circle.shape('circle')
        self.circle.shapesize(self.size,self.size,1)

    #positions circle random x top y
    def posit(self):
        number = random.randint(-340,340)
        self.circle.ht()
        self.circle.penup()

        self.size_color()
        self.circle.goto(number,self.ypos)
        self.circle.st()

    #substracts from y position for falling effect
    #should substract from score as well
    def drop(self):
        self.posit()
        while True:
            self.ypos = self.ypos- 4
            self.circle.sety(self.ypos)
            if self.ypos <= -300:
                self.player.score = self.player.score - 10
                print(self.player.score)
                self.ypos = 300
                self.posit()

class Player:
    def __init__(self,score=200):
        self.score = score

def display_screen():
    window = t.Screen()
    window.bgcolor('black')

display_screen()
c = Circle(2)
c.drop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Barmar stole my answer. Use what he said, however don't forget to change `this.player` to `self.player` as he made a tiny mistake, probably because of other programming languages.